# Python suddenly cannot find files only when I want to rename or copy them

Tags: python

I'm trying to very simply copy a load of files from one directory to another and then rename the files (to replace whitespaces and %20 with _). In my root directory, I have:

- optimiser.py (what I use to run the script)
- Folder (named 'Files to Improve' containing basic text files)
- Folder (named 'Finished' where I want every file to be copied to (empty))

It seems that the files can be found because this code successfully prints every file (and their respective new filenames):

```
import os
from shutil import copyfile

files_to_improve_dir = 'Files to Improve'
finished_files_dir = 'Finished'

for f in os.listdir(files_to_improve_dir):
    new_filename = f.replace(' ','_').replace('%20','_').lower()
    print('f:', f, '--- n:', new_filename)
```

The first problem occurs when I add `copyfile(f, finished_files_dir)` to the bottom, returning this error:

```
f: FILE.txt --- n: file.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "optimiser.py", line 10, in <module>
    copyfile(f, finished_files_dir)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 259, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'FILE.txt'
```

Does anyone know what this error is and why it occurs?

Secondly, if I instead add this to the bottom instead of the copy file line:

```
if (f != new_filename):
        os.rename(f, new_filename)
```

It returns this error instead:

```
f: FILE.txt --- n: file.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "optimiser.py", line 12, in <module>
    os.rename(f, new_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'FILE.txt' -> 'file.txt'
```

I don't know why it suddenly now cannot find the files, despite it printing them in the previous code. If it couldn't find the files, how could it have printed them?

Thanks for any help here. The complete code is below:

```
import os
from shutil import copyfile

files_to_improve_dir = 'Files to Improve'
finished_files_dir = 'Finished'

for f in os.listdir(files_to_improve_dir):
    new_filename = f.replace(' ','_').replace('%20','_').lower()
    print('f:', f, '--- n:', new_filename)
    copyfile(f, finished_files_dir) #error 1
    if (f != new_filename): #error 2
        os.rename(f, new_filename) #error 2
```

Comment: `copyfile` function don't know to where look for your files, try passing absolute paths

Comment: running this returns true print(os.path.isdir(files_to_improve_dir)) so I assume it knows it's a directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your

```
copyfile(f, finished_files_dir) #error 1
```

to

```
copyfile(os.path.join(files_to_improve_dir, f),
         os.path.join(finished_files_dir, f))
```

and

```
os.rename(f, new_filename) #error 2
```

to

```
os.rename(os.path.join(files_to_improve_dir, f),
          os.path.join(files_to_improve_dir, new_filename))
```

One more hint: When renaming your file, there might araise duplicates (e.g. `bla bla` and `bla%20bla` will both be renamed to `bla_bla`), so you may want to check if the destination exists already...